# kendo UI bar chart - how do series data show percentage display

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I am using the bar chart of kendo ui.
I'm trying to create stacked bar chart like this:
https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/bar-charts/stacked100-bar

however, i want to one of actual series data percentage for maximum value(100%- stack :type="100%") in kendo barchart.

### Here is my sample code :

```
function createExecutionToday(type) {
    var running =/*[[#{dashboard.Executing}]]*/;
    var success =/*[[#{dashboard.Success}]]*/;
    var check =/*[[#{dashboard.Check}]]*/;

    $("#" + type).kendoChart({
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "dashboard/" + type + ".json",
                    dataType: "json"
                }
            },
            schema: {
                data: function (response) {
                    for (i in response) {
                        var status = response[i].status;
                        response[i].status = toKorean(status);

                    }
                    return response;
                }
            },

        },
        legend: {
            visible: false
        },
        chartArea: {
            background: "#F8F8F8"
        },
        seriesDefaults: {
            type: "bar",
            labels: {
                visible: true,
                background: "transparent",
            },

            overlay: null
        },
        series: [{

            field: "count",
            statck: { type: "100%" },
            color: function (status) {
                var colors = ["#66CCFF", "#DB7196", "#E5B055"];
                return colors[status.index];
            }
        }],

        categoryAxis: {
            categories: [running, success, check],
            majorGridLines: {
                visible: false
            },
            line: {
                visible: false
            },
            labels: {
                font: "15px arial"
            }
        },
        valueAxis: {
            labels: {
                format: "{0}%"
            },
            line: {
                visible: false
            },
            labels: {
                visible: false
            },
            majorGridLines: {
                visible: false
            },
        },
        tooltip: {
            visible: true,

            template: "#= series.field #: #= value #"
        },

    });
}
```

series type: 100% is it impossible to implement by option?
Do you have any idea?

[image]

Comment: Can you create a simple jsFiddle/DOJO/Codepen with hard coded data that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: You have a typo: statck:{type:"100%"}, Change to stack